# Preserve array when submitting a form to a JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have a form that takes in data and writes to a JSON form in PHP.

I needed to submit an array as a numeric input but it keeps giving me a string. Is it possible to enable the form to submit as an array via text input box?

Form example:

```
<input type="text" name="arraytobepushed[]" placeholder="EG: 1000,2000,3000" />
```

The output is:

```
{
"obj": [{
   "arraytobepushed": ["1000,2000,3000"]
       }]
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an array type in HTML inputs. If you want an array from a string input delimited by commas, you have to split the string yourself.

Comment: simply you can not write `array` into `html` input box and think it will going to treat as `array` in `php`. it will be treated as a string. So put comma separated values and then in `php` `explode()` that .it's easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the text into an array by using `explode()` So you would have something like this:

```
<?PHP
  $myArray = explode(',', $_POST['arraytobepushed[]']);
?>
```

The `explode()` function splits everything separated by the first argument (in this case a comma) you pass and puts it into an array.

So if your inputted was `1000, 2000, 3000` your `$myArray` would look like:

index 0 = "1000" (`$myArray[0]`)

index 1 = "2000" (`$myArray[1]`)

index 2 = "3000" (`$myArray[2]`)

Keep in mind that the values are still strings, not integers. If you want to make them integers you can do this:

```
$myArray = array_map('intval', explode(',', $_POST['arraytobepushed[]']));
```

This makes all your elements into integers like so:

index 0 = 1000 (`$myArray[0]`)

index 1 = 2000 (`$myArray[1]`)

index 2 = 3000 (`$myArray[2]`)

Answer (score 0):

No. Forms submit text.

PHP special cases fields with `[]` in the name as fields to be expressed in an array. It has no special case feature to treat a field as a number instead of a string. You need to convert the data explicitly.